# How to integrate Watson Discovery with Watson Virtual Agent?

Tags: watson-virtual-agent

How to integrate Watson Discovery with Watson Virtual Agent? Can anyone give hints, sample code and provide documentation link? https://github.com/watson-virtual-agents/chat-widget does not contain information regarding this? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to use a custom code with 2 APIs endpoint: Discovery and Virtual agent/ Conversation.

For now, have one example with Conversation Service and Discovery Service in Java, from IBM Developers, you can see in [this link](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-with-discovery).

And a few weeks ago I built some simple example using the project conversation-simple for integrating Discovery, using the highlight and another custom `params`, using Node.js, you can see in [this link](https://github.com/sayurimizuguchi/conversation-with-discovery)

After creates one IBM Cloud (Bluemix), go to *Catalog* and Select the Watson services above, pay attention to the *Services credentials* when you click in your Watson Service for use each service, as you can see in my `.env` and IBM Professionals [file](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-with-discovery/blob/master/src/main/resources/server.env), for all works, you need to paste the values into the [Enviroment Variables](https://github.com/sayurimizuguchi/conversation-with-discovery/blob/master/.env.example) or *replace* the values with the respective variables in your code.

- See the Official [Documentation](https://developer.ibm.com/api/view/virtualagent-prod:watson-virtual-agent-public:title-Watson_Virtual_Agent#doc) for Using Watson Virtual Agent instead of Conversation.
- See the Official [Documentation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/discovery/index.html) and [API Reference](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/discovery/api/v1/) for use Watson Discovery.
- See the Official [Documentation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/index.html) and [API Reference](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/) for use Watson Conversation.